# Struts2 - getting 404 Resource Unavailable error from request page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, http-status-code-404, jsp-tags

I'm trying to write a login example that takes the user to a success.jsp if username equals password and an error message if it doesn't. The error message works but success (username=password) results in a 404 (HTTP Status 404 - /Struts2Ch4/success.jsp)

I experienced a similar problem in a previous post. I had not declared the RESULT parameter in the class. I was advised to use annotations in the class file and this solved the problem. In this case both the success and result parameters seem to be declared by the class so I'm not sure why I'm getting 404.

alias.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <html> 
    <head>
    <title><s:text name="app.title"/></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
    </head>
<body>
<table align="center" width="300">
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><s:actionerror/></td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2">Enter Login ID and Password</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">
    <s:form action="aliasing" method="post">
    <s:textfield name="uname" key="app.loginid"/>
    <s:password name="pwd" key="app.password"/>
    <s:submit value="Enter"/>
    </s:form>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td align="center" colspan="2">
<a href="index.jsp">B a c k</a></td>
</tr>
</table>        
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

   <struts>
 <package name="default" extends="struts-default">
 <global-exception-mappings>
    <exception-mapping exception="java.lang.Exception" result="exception"/>
 </global-exception-mappings>


 <action name="aliasing" class="com.manaar.action.AliasAction">
    <param name="aliases">#{ 'uname' : 'loginid','pwd' : 'password' }</param>
    <interceptor-ref name="alias"/>
    <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>        
    <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
    <result name="error">/alias.jsp</result>    
    <result name="input">/alias.jsp</result>        
</action>




</package>

</struts>
```

AliasAction.java

```
package com.manaar.action;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class AliasAction extends ActionSupport {
private String loginid;
private String password;

public String getLoginid() {
    return loginid;
}   
public void setLoginid(String loginid) {
    this.loginid = loginid;
}   
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String execute() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Login Id: "+getLoginid());
    System.out.println("Password: "+getPassword());
    if(loginid.equals(password))
        return SUCCESS;
    else{
        this.addActionError(getText("app.invalid"));
        return ERROR;
    }           
}       
}
```

success.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
 <html>
 <head><title><s:text name="app.title"/></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
 </head>
 <body>
 <div align="center">
 <h1><s:text name="app.success"/></h1>
 The action has returned SUCCESS as result code.<br><br>
 <a href="index.jsp">Back to Index</a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org    /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    /web-app_3_0.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"/>
<html>
<head><title><s:text name="app.title"/></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<table align="center" width=400>
<tr><td><h2>Sruts 2 Interceptors</h2></td></tr>

<tr><td><s:a href="alias.jsp">Interceptor Example 1</s:a></td></tr>
<tr><td>alias, basicStack </td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><s:a href="model.jsp">Interceptor Example 2</s:a></td></tr>
<tr><td>
exception, prepare, debugging, model-driven, params, conversionError, workflow  
</td></tr>  
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<s:a href="servletAction.action">Interceptor Example 3</s:a>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>servlet-config, scoped-model-driven </td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><s:a href="longAction.action">Interceptor Example 4</s:a></td></tr>
<tr><td>completeStack, execAndWait</td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
<tr><td><s:a href="login.jsp">Interceptor Example 5</s:a> </td></tr>
<tr><td>basicStack, validation, workflow, scope </td></tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the JSP file in your webapp's deployment directory tree?

Comment: This is not the same, post the `web.xml` and path to the `success.jsp`.

Comment: I've added the web.xml and corresponding index.jsp